# Merge a column containing strings with a column containing floats

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a (geo)dataframe with a column with location names and column with floats and I would like to merge them.

Example with cities dataset in geopandas (with an extra column):

```
 Name          geometry    GDP
Vatican City  POINT(...)  20353.42
```

I want to merge them so I have: Vatican City: 20353.42
What I tried:

```
cities['name-gdp'] = cities['name'].astype(str).str.cat(cities['GDP'], sep =': ')
```

But I get the following error:
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Is possible some `NaN`s values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems need convert float `GDP` column to `string`s:

```
cities['name-gdp'] = cities['name'].str.cat(cities['GDP'].astype(str), sep =': ')
```

But if some `NaN`s and need output as `NaN`s:

```
cities = pd.DataFrame({'name':['q','w','e'], 'GDP':[10.5,20.3, np.nan]})
print (cities)
    GDP name
0  10.5    q
1  20.3    w
2   NaN    e

gdp = cities['GDP'].mask(cities['GDP'].notnull(),cities['GDP'].astype(str))
print (gdp)
0    10.5
1    20.3
2     NaN
Name: GDP, dtype: object

print (gdp.apply(type))
0      <class 'str'>
1      <class 'str'>
2    <class 'float'>
Name: GDP, dtype: object

cities['name-gdp'] = cities['name'].astype(str).str.cat(gdp, sep =': ')
print (cities)
    GDP name name-gdp
0  10.5    q  q: 10.5
1  20.3    w  w: 20.3
2   NaN    e      NaN
```

First solution is possible use too, but then working with string `nan` and get:

```
cities['name-gdp'] = cities['name'].str.cat(cities['GDP'].astype(str), sep =': ')
print (cities)
     GDP name name-gdp
0  10.5    q  q: 10.5
1  20.3    w  w: 20.3
2   NaN    e   e: nan
```